# Noise in a voltage converter output

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter

I plan to use [this](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC1046) 5V to -5V voltage converter: 
And here is the recommended use:

[image]

But in LTspice I get very bad noise in -5V output.

Is that expected? Any idea why or how to remove this noise?

[image]

Comment: Completely normal, and what you see there is actually quite small, in reality it might be larger, on the order of tens of millivolts to hundreds and gets worse with increasing load, huurayy! Jokes aside, it is one of the design parameters of all switched circuits. The noise that you can tolerate that is. You can use filters and ferrite beads on the output to mitigate this to whatever noise level you want, depending on your resources.

Comment: Very bad noise? A well-designed switching converter can often have a noise spec of 1% of the DC rail. When you build the circuit you will see "real" noise, not just the simulated stuff. Then we can talk.

Comment: @AdamLawrence OP just told me he "wondered whether the example was wrong", and doesn't even necessarily *need* cleaner voltage. So: this is a waste of time.

Comment: No. I asked to be sure if their implementation is correct or maybe a software bug. Now I learned it is(the noise) expected. So it wasnt waste of time dont worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it **is** a switched-capacitance inverter, so yeah, oscillations on the output are inevitable, and yours have an amplitude of 20mV – that's not very much!

My guess is that with a minimal amount of loading the output, you'll get a different picture.

As with every signal, voltage supplies can be filtered. It might reduce the accuracy, but improve the noise, to have a simple LC low pass (L in series, C to GND) at the output.

Comment: I need a +-5V for an instrumentation amplifier. What ever the cap I tried I couldnt remove this noise. is there a better performance IC with a cleaner output?

Comment: I didn't say "use another cap". Read my answer in detail.

Comment: maybe I dont need to filter this for AD8221's negative rail, it doesnt effect the output I guess. I was just wondering if their suggestion is wrong or not.

Comment: yeah, because random guys on the internet should be checking the datasheet circuits of the guys selling power supply ICs. Thanks for investing my time so wisely.

Comment: Actually more like 2 mV, which is a silly small amount.

Comment: Classic XY problem!

Comment: @winny's right. For those who wonder: http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

Put this on each of the two outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn849d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your switching rate looks like 10Khz or faster. A 160 Hz LPF, or 100 Ohms and 10uF, should reduce the amplitude of your trash.